# Leetcode Sqrt(x) comparing two algorithm runtime

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I had two approaches to the Sqrt(x) problem on leetcode, first was to use Bablonian method and the second to use Bakshali method. I thought the Bakshali method would be more efficient as its a quadratic convergence which means two iterations of the Bablonian method is equivalent to the Bakshali method, but after submitting both on leetcode Bablonian was faster. Why is this?

[image: Leetcode Sqrt(x) problem]

Bablonian Method

```
if x <= 1:
    return x
else:
    x_0 = len(str(x)) * (10**2)
    change = 1
    while change > 0.01:
        x_n = 0.5 * (x_0 + x/x_0)
        change = abs(x_0-x_n)
        x_0 = x_n
            
return int(x_0)
```

Bakshali Method

```
if x <= 1:
    return x
else:
    x_0 = 0.5 * x
    change = 1
    while change > 0.01:
        a_n = (x - x_0**2)/(2*x_0)
        b_n = x_0 + a_n
        change = abs((x_0**2)-x)
        x_0 = b_n - (a_n**2)/(2*b_n)
                
return int(x_0)
```

Comment: If each Bakshali iteration takes more than twice as long as each Babylonian iteration then Bakshali will be slower. Count the number of multiplications and divisions in each iteration of both.

Comment: @paisanco Fair enough ill edit it out to avoid any confusion :)

Comment: _but after submitting both on leetcode Bablonian was faster_ regardless of the case, don't compare algorithm runtimes with leetcode runtimes since LC runtime is inconsistent as it depends on server. resource availability etc. You can run the same on your machine in the IDE and compare for much fairer and precise results.

Comment: Have you tried an integer variant of Newton-Raphson?

Comment: Note that the choice of starting guess is important, and you're using very different starting guesses for the two methods. (The `len(str(x)) * (10**2)` starting guess is a bit odd; what's the reasoning for that one?)